# Magento: How to exclude image from gallery programmatically?

Tags: magento

I am creating products and images programmatically. The only thing that is not working is the "exclude from gallery" feature.

See http://snag.gy/QGhPg.jpg for details.

How would I set that in the code? My current code looks like that:

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($myImage, array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false);
```

The flag is called `disabled` I think, not sure though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For example, disable all images for a product

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(12345);
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
$attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
$mediaGalleryAttribute = $attributes['media_gallery'];
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $mediaGalleryAttribute->getBackend()->updateImage($product, $image['file'], array('exclude' => true));
}
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($myImage, array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, true);
```

The last parameter should be set to `true` to exclude the image from gallery.

See: `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..first save product and insert image

```
$productid=10; // Product id of that product which image you want to update
//for remove existing Images
$loadpro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);
$mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
$mediaApiItems = $mediaApi->items($loadpro->getId());

foreach($mediaApiItems as $item) {
  $datatemp=$mediaApi->remove($loadpro->getId(), $item['file']);
}
$loadpro->save(); //before adding need to save product

//for add new images
$loadpro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($loadpro->getId());  
$loadpro->addImageToMediaGallery($loadpro, array ('image','small_image','thumbnail'), true, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mediaArray = array(
        'thumbnail'   => $oscProduct['products_image'],
        'small_image' => $oscProduct['products_mediumimage'],
        'image'       => $oscProduct['products_largeimage'],
    );

    // Remove unset images, add image to gallery if exists
    $importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/';

    foreach ( $mediaArray as $imageType => $fileName ) {
        $filePath = $importDir . $fileName;
        if ( file_exists($filePath) ) {
            try {
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            echo "Product does not have an image or the path is incorrect. Path was: {$filePath}<br/>";
        }
    }
```

**Note:** $imageType is not an array, as your counterpart is.

**Edit:** You only want one image, and to set it as each type. After you save the product with $product->save(), try something like the following, assuming you have set the image type already:

```
$product->setThumbnail($product->getImage());
$product->setSmallImage($product->getImage());
$product->save();
```